# I don't see the slightest change in my ZZ plant after about 3 months of re-potting it

Tags: houseplants, leaves

I've been looking after my Zamiifolia for like 3 months with adequate sunlight, soil and everything, but it refuses to get any taller, or even leaf out. The current leaves are healthy & shiny but I'm losing patience to see it grow like my other plants. It came to my attention though that the main stem is getting significantly thicker, but no other progress.
How much more do you think I should keep waiting?

Comment: What is adequate sunlight?  Soil?  This plant is beloved by indoor plant enthusiasts because it is able to handle low light, dry dry air.  It will not grow fast. If it is healthy leave it alone.  It is on its own lifeline.  Plants indoors will never be like the plants out of doors.  I take all my indoor plants out of doors beneath a covered porch during growing season.  They are able to get far more light and make more food for themselves to last the winter.  What other plants are you comparing this guy with?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the plant and its pot please?

Comment: Sure thing: [link](https://imgur.com/a/CJkX139)
This is a close-up of the plant, followed by 2 more pics for comparison purposes. These two pots are more or less the same age, but as you can see differ in height and size, remarkably. 
@stormy: I'm well aware that houseplants are quite tolerant species, but I tend to shower them by sunlight, as long as it speeds up their growth, because, why not?

Comment: There appears to be a new sideshoot near the base, but otherwise, what soil did you use in the pot, and did you clean and sterilize that pot before use (I can see limescale deposits round the inside which indicates its been used before). And how often (and how much) do you water?

Comment: That sideshoot has been there as long as I can remember. Yes the pot was used before and neither cleaned nor sterilized. Does it matter? :D
I used a combination of perlite, peat, compost and some loose normal soil I always use for my pots. Moreover, I water the plant every other day, not more than the size of a cup. The white limescale deposit you detected inside is caused by the poor quality of the camera btw.

Comment: My *ZZ* was doing so well that I had to split it. After the split, it took a full year before I saw much new growth. I think the roots object to being disturbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the extra information. Yes, it does matter whether the pot is thoroughly cleaned after previous use for something else, because it may have traces of pathogens from a previous occupant. No matter, what's done is done now, although the pot you used seems too large for such a small plant - a size or two down would have been better.

For houseplants or plants in pots, it is not a good idea to use any compost you've made yourself in the pot, unless your compost was produced aerobically (meaning you turned it at least twice a week every week). Compost not produced in this way doesn't get hot enough and may contain pathogens which, whilst okay in open soil, are not okay contained in a pot.

You've said you used some 'normal' soil, which I take to mean soil from the garden outside - again, this is not a good idea for the same reasons cited above in regard to compost,i.e., possible pathogen content. New potting soil is always best - it contains a small amount of nutrients, is sterile and you can certainly add perlite or similar to it to improve drainage.

If you haven't used any fertilizer, then you should; I don't know what's available where you are, but something like Baby Bio would be good. As for watering, stop watering so often. It's better to let the soil dry out a little at the top, then water thoroughly, allowing the pot to drain freely, and ensuring no water is left in any outer tray or pot after 30 minutes.

With regard to light, this plant does not appreciate direct sunlight - it grows faster in bright light, and in bright light, will need watering more often because it will grow a little faster and the soil will dry out more quickly. They are fairly slow growing plants, and yours does not look particularly unhealthy, but you might improve the situation by changing your watering regime, placing it appropriately in terms of light, and fertilizing it. https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/zz-plant.html

I'd be inclined to find a smaller pot (depending on how big the rootball is, if its got one) and decant the plant and repot into that, using proper potting soil instead. Whether you lose patience because of its slow growth and want to bin it is entirely up to you...there's not very much wrong with the plant except it's not really growing at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer. I agree, the pot is too big for that plant but I thought it might help double size my ZZ. I might have lost patience of its growth but why would I ever bin it? :) That decision is off the list, forever.

Comment: Oh good, glad to hear it - the plant's hanging in there despite less than ideal growing conditions, it deserves a chance!

Comment: ZZ seems to like a spring march April rainy seasons. Got 5 new stems and a flower this year: https://www.google.com/search?q=zamioculcas+zamiifolia+flower&client=tablet-android-samsung&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpiMW1lYvbAhVGu1MKHQxUDWUQ_AUIESgB&biw=768&bih=1024&dpr=2